# Spark - save sparse vectors to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to vectorise my data using spark tf/idf-like functions. So, as an output I get very long sparse vectors of features where only few indexes have values.

I was thinking to save such vectors into MongoDB array-like objects, having present indexes as keys. So, for example a SparseVector like

```
(23,[0,15],[1.0,1.0])
```

would be converted into MongoDB object as follows:

```
{"0": 1.0, "15": 1.0}
```

How can I do it using spark scala and mongodb connector?
I should probably implement some kind of UDF but not sure what type would fit mongodb as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.
Here's the udf I defined to convert SparseVectors to BSON-convertable Map.

```
val makeSparseMapUdf = udf {
    (vec: SparseVector) => vec.indices
      .map((index) => (index.toString, vec.toArray(index)))
      .toMap
}
```